# Flashing Text in Corona SDK lua

Tags: lua, coronasdk

this is not working, how I want. when I do this it only transitions once from black to white but if I remove the parameter textToFlash and leave it blank and put myTextObject in where the rest of the textToFlash objects in the function it works and flashes with different colors.

```
local myTextObject = display.newText("Hello, World", 160, 25, "Arial", 60)

function flashing_text(textToFlash)
    local r = math.random(0,100)
    local g = math.random(0,100)
    local b = math.random(0, 100)

    if(textToFlash.alpha < 1) then
        textToFlash:setFillColor(r/100,g/100,b/100)
        transition.to( textToFlash, {time=490, alpha=1})
    else 
        transition.to( textToFlash, {time=490, alpha=0.1})
    end
end
txt_flash = timer.performWithDelay(550, flashing_text(myTextObject), 0)
```

can someone make this work? any help or feedback would be thanked

Answer (score 1):

In order for your function to work. You must add **function() end** inside your timer function. like this **timer.performWithDelay(delay, function() callYourOtherfunction() end, 0)**

```
local myTextObject = display.newText("Hello, World", 160, 25, "Arial", 60)

function flashing_text(textToFlash)
    local r = math.random(0,100)
    local g = math.random(0,100)
    local b = math.random(0, 100)

    if(textToFlash.alpha < 1) then
        textToFlash:setFillColor(r/100,g/100,b/100)
        transition.to( textToFlash, {time=490, alpha=1})
    else 
        transition.to( textToFlash, {time=490, alpha=0.1})
    end
end
txt_flash = timer.performWithDelay(550, function() flashing_text(myTextObject) end, 0)
```

Cheers. Working in my simulator mate. Happy Coding.